# itertools.groupby key func to produce groupings of zero and non-zero values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

Does anyone have an idea how I would make use of the *key* func argument in the itertools.groupby function to group rows of data by zero and non-zero values?

For a simplified example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby

FakeRow = namedtuple('FakeRow', ['start_date_time', 'wear_sensor', 
                                 'part_number', 'chip_count'])

data = [
    FakeRow(1,1,'999-045', 0),
    FakeRow(2,1,'999-045', 4),
    FakeRow(3,1,'999-045', 3),
    FakeRow(3,1,'999-047', 0),
    FakeRow(4,1,'999-045', 0),
    FakeRow(5,1,'999-047', 1),
]                         

# need to groupby start date time first
unique_keys = []
groups = []
data = sorted(data, key=attrgetter('start_date_time'))

# want to group by 'chip_count' but by zero and non-zero values
for k, g in groupby(data, key=my_key_func(*args)):
    groups.append(list(g))
    unique_keys.append(k)

def my_key_func(*args):
    '''Help itertools.groupby group by zeros, or group by anything non-zero'''
    pass
```

The desired output would be:

```
groups == [
    [FakeRow(1,1,'999-045', 0)],
    [FakeRow(2,1,'999-045', 4),FakeRow(3,1,'999-045', 3)],
    [FakeRow(3,1,'999-047', 0), FakeRow(4,1,'999-045', 0)],
    [FakeRow(5,1,'999-047', 1)]
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as looking at the boolean value of the fake row's chip_count:

```
def my_key_func(fakerow):
    return bool(fakerow.chip_count)
```

In this case, your `unique_keys` will be `True` or `False` which is likely not what you want.  You'd probably want to use a set and `update` with the `fakerow.chip_count` instead:

```
unique_keys = set()
for k, g in groupby(data, key=my_key_func):
    group = list(g)
    groups.append(group)
    unique_keys.update(fk.chip_count for fk in group)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I ended up making the loop: for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: bool(x.chip_count)) which worked. It didn't like the *args. I got an error saying that args was not defined.

Comment: @PlacidLush -- Sorry, it should have just been `key=my_key_func`, not `key=my_key_func(*args)`.

Comment: No worries. That little nuance helped me to better understand what was going on.